# All ways getting AttributeError while installing CSV module

Tags: python, machine-learning, pip

```
enter code here[how to to install the module][1]
```

I cannot able to install this CSV module
[1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQndX.jpg

Comment: Why are you trying to install `csv` module. It is already in the `stdlib`. Just `import csv`. Or is this some different `csv` module ?

Comment: You wrote `pip intsall` instead of `pip install` - that's a typo. And as the other commentator said: CSV is already part of Python's standard library and thus doesn't need to be installed with pip, it's already included in the base Python installation. You only need to import csv in the modules where you want to use it.

Comment: Copying text in Your console and pasting it as formatted text would be much faster than taking an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

csv is a default module in python3. But if there is an error in importing the module, there could have been an error while downloading python (that is if you aren't using python on cmd and on a text editor). I recommend you reinstall the editor. And also could you please tell if you are able to install any other packages/modules via pip? Because if you cannot install modules via pip, there definitely was some kind of an error while downloading pip too.